# Weird Error when using atof in c

Tags: c

I understand there are bugs with "Bad Input" but for some reason i cant even get good input to go through. It's either returning a value of 10 or 0 and i can't seem to find the reason why. Below is where i am calling it:

- `var1` is datatype float. All headers are included that are needed.
- `floatHolder` is datatype char array.

**Below is where i am calling it:**

```
scanf("%s", &floatHolder);
var1 = inputchecker(floatHolder);
```

this is the function that is called:

```
float inputchecker(char *charArray)
{

float f = 0;
float f2 = 0;
int i = 0;
int z = 0;
int badInput = 0;
char errorArray[15];
func1:

while (i<strlen(charArray))
{
    if (charArray[i]<48 || charArray[i]>57)
    {
        if (charArray[i] == 46)
        {
            i++;
            goto func1;
        }
        printf("\n Entered value contains alphabets or symbols, please enter numerical/Floating point values only.\n");
        printf("Re-enter Correct Input Please: ");
        scanf("%s", &errorArray);
        getchar();
        badInput = 1;
        goto func2;
    }
    i++;
}
func2:
while (z < strlen(errorArray) && badInput == 1)
{
    if (errorArray[i] < 48 || errorArray[i]>57)
    {
        if (errorArray[i] == 46)
        {
            z++;
            goto func2;
        }
        printf("Re-enter Correct Input Please: ");
        scanf("%s", &errorArray);
        getchar();

    }
    z++;
}

badInput = 0;
f = atof(charArray);
f2 = atof(errorArray);

if (f == 0)
{
    return f2;
}
if (f2 == 0)
{
    return f;
}
}
```

For some reason after the function is called it shows a correct return value ex. if i give it 4 it will return 4 but var1 will show a insanely large number, 0, and 10. If anyone can let me know what i'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: When you say it will "show" the wrong number, maybe there is a `printf` statement that you are not showing us??

Comment: What is the contents of `errorArray[]` in `while (z < strlen(errorArray)...` if prior `scanf("%s", &errorArray);` is never called?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the two `while` loops? Just throw `charArray` in `atof` and handle any errors ...

Comment: Aside: I can see from the first 2-line snippet that `floatHolder` must be an array of `char`, so  `scanf("%s", &floatHolder);` should be `scanf("%s", floatHolder);` and similarly `scanf("%s", &errorArray);` should be `scanf("%s", errorArray);`. Also please avoid magic numbers, presumably `46` and `48` and `57` are supposed to be `'.'` and `'0'` and `'9'`.

Comment: @WeatherVane there should also be a length limiter in scanf format string. Plain `%s` is no better than `gets`

Comment: Don't just tell us that all needed headers are included, show us. See [mcve]

Comment: @M.M yes there should, but it is the OP who needs that info. I already put enough for a comment.

Comment: If having `goto func1`; and `goto func2;` within a single function is not a sign that you should actually have two functions, then I don't know what is.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your routine and received similar results.  Then I realized what you problem is.  You probably neglected to put a function prototype at the top of your file.

```
float inputchecker(char *charArray);
```

By neglecting to use a prototype the compiler will have to guess the signature of the function and the stack may not be restored properly and your return value then will be corrupted.

When I added the prototype at the top of the file, everything worked fine for valid float inputs such as 3.14

Note: different versions of C will behave differently. For example C89/C90 will 'guess' what the parameters will be without a prototype.  This can be quite dangerous and it is what I think happened in your situation. I think C99 works in a similar way but with some differences.

Another, proof that you are not using a prototype is that you are receiving integer answers. When the compiler 'guesses' the prototype, it will typically return an int. Furthermore, this also explains why you are getting the same results for different input, you are getting the contents of the same memory location (not your f variables) due to the stack corruption.

Its very very good practice to always define function protoypes at the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you so much this 100% fixed it, i can't believe i didn't think about that. Silly mistakes are always the ones that mess us up the most.